# Is it possible to add buttons to MiniController and ExtendedController?

Tags: android, chromecast, castcompanionlibrary

I'm using the Companion library for casting video from my app to the Chromecast.

Is there any way to add STOP button to `MiniController` and `ExpandedController`? Currently there's only a Play/Pause button.

Comment: In documentation nothing about possibility to add buttons. What can i try? Maybe somebody knows way to do this. Now STOP button appear only when casting streaming video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to add a stop button to the stock version of these components. You can, however, extend them and add your additional button(s).